# Error when test for spatial correlation with slmtest in spatial panel data

Tags: r, error-handling, spatial, economics

I'm trying to test spatial correlation of a ***plm*** object using ***slmtest*** function from ***splm*** package and I receive this error:

```
Error in as.spam(x) : coercion not defined form this class
```

**I searched for this error but I didn't find a solution.**

---

First, I defined a panel regression:

```
plinear <- plm(formula=regre, data=sdataframe, model="pooling")
```

Then I try to run the LM tests:

```
LMlag <- slmtest(plinear, listw=rainha.listw, test="lml")
```

so I receive the mentioned error which I have no idea it comes from...

Any tips?